# document.save("output.pdf") RuntimeError: Proxy error(ArgumentNullException): Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

Tags: python, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I have the following code:

```
import aspose.pdf as pdf

# Load input PDF document
document = pdf.Document("some_pdf.pdf")

# Initialize the TeXSaveOptions
texSaveOptions = pdf.TeXSaveOptions()

# Convert the PDF to TEX file
document.save("PDFToTEX.tex", texSaveOptions)

print("Rendering process completed")
```

When saving the document using `aspose.pdf` it gives the error as `Value cannot be null`. Using the latest version for aspose.pdf

I tried to add license and play over it. Did not help. However `aspose.words` works as exptected.

Comment: We request you please create a topic in our dedicated support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where you can easily share the problematic files. Please note that it is the right and recommended place to discuss such issues. Please post there and we will further proceed to assist you accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.